# Write a loop that will iterate over a list of items and only output items which have letters inside of a string

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So this is my code in python:

```
names = ['John', ' ', 'Amanda', 5]
valid = []
for correct_names in names:
    if correct_names.isalpha():
        valid.append(correct_names)
print(valid)
```

but when I initialize it I am getting:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha' I am planning to have an output of
`['John', 'Amanda']`

without using regular expressions as I am working my way up in learning python again.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `if str(correct_names).isalpha():`

Comment: ^ ... because not all items in your list are strings.

Comment: Question: _has letters_, does that mean "Foo 2" is in (it has letters) or out (It has other things too).

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Thank you Ashwin it looks like I missed that part because I was so focused on the names. It makes sense adding ```str(correct_names)``` to capture everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is for two restrictions: 1) its a string, 2) it has letters. Use `isinstance` for the first and search the string for an alpha for the second.

```
names = ['John', ' ', 'Amanda', 5]
valid = []
for correct_names in names:
    if isinstance(correct_names, str):
        for c in correct_names:
            if c.isalpha():
                valid.append(correct_names)
                break
print(valid)
```